# Can triggerhappy be used to load multiple keysets of functionality?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, triggerhappy

I recently wrote a script with a loop that will switch out the functionality of a set of key presses based on a set of other keypresses.

I'm starting to think the same can be done with triggerhappy.

So for instance, if you press `1`, the `q` key is assigned functionality `a()`, `w` is assigned functionality `b()`, and `e` is assigned the functionality `c()` when pressed.

But if I press `2` then the `q` key is assigned functionality `d()`, and `w` is assigned the functionality `e()`, and `e` is assigned the functionality `f().`

My thought is that it would be something like assigning an event to `KEY_1` which would call `thd --triggers <path-to-events-for-file-1>` and replace the functionalities with (the same thing for `KEY_1-KEY_2`) and replace the following: `q:a() w:b() c:()`

And that it would do the same with `KEY_2` except that instead the keys would be `q:d() w:e() e:f()`

Where `<letter>()` is a bash command.

Is that correct?